# can I set json to be pretty print only in some attributes?

Tags: java, json, string, printing

I have a json with many attributes.

I want some of them to be inline. Meaning with `no new break lines`.

Here is my code today:

```
private String serializeToJson(T item) {
    String json;
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(item);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        json = "";
    }
    return json;
}
```

how can I set it to be not "pretty print" for attribute `path` like this `{ "path" : { "segmentId" : 31788674, "nodeId" : 26161441, "x" : -74.236605 ...`

Answer (score 0):

I serialized this specific property to inline json string separately.

```
public ResultUiShort(ResultLong result) {
    this.path =  stringUtils.toInlineJson(result.path);
    ...
```

}

and

```
public <T> String toInlineJson(T item) {
    String json;
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(item);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        json = "";
    }
    return json;
}
```